# 400 Bad request when posting json array to spring controller on azure

Tags: azure, spring-mvc

I am getting 400 bad request when I am trying to pass a json array to spring controller on azure app service. However I am not getting any error when I try to run the service from my local environment. My request is as follows,

```
$http.post(appPath + '/app/temp/saveTempData?tempData=' + JSON.stringify(row.data)).success(function(result) {

            if (result.result) {

                toaster.pop("successful", "Updated successfully");
            } else {
                toaster.pop("warning", "Something went wrong please try again later.");
            }
        })
```

Where row.data is an json array.On the spring controller I have the following,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveTempData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String saveTempData(@RequestParam JSONArray tempData) {



}
```

This code is working in my local machine, but on the azure app service it gives me 400 bad request. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to encode the request parameter when sending json array to the app service controller using encodeURIComponent like follows,

```
$http.post(appPath + '/app/temp/saveTempData?tempData=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(row.data))).success(function(result) {

            if (result.result) {

                toaster.pop("successful", "Updated successfully");
            } else {
                toaster.pop("warning", "Something went wrong please try again later.");
            }
        })
```